# MySQL: best way to save more than 60 values to different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I want to make an application to save a hand-written paper contract in my database. Each contract has over 60 values to save. I already made the database with 15 tables with primary and foreign keys. My question is what is the best way to save all this data, using one procedure or multiple queries.

What I tried is to create a stored procedure and pass all this values as parameters. And then execute a query in php where I call and pass all values like this:

```
CALL SaveContract(11111, "Name", "Surname", 22222, "User", "Password", 'm', "2017-09-06", "norm", "sup", "asac", 29, 5, 7, 125, 3, 123456, 456789, "kiss", "bot", 123, "en", "ram", 33333, "aaaaa", "bbbb", 'm', "2017-09-12", "ccccc", "dddddd", null, null, null, null,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null , 1,null , 1, null,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,null , 10, '["","",""]')
```

Although I get an error (#1436 - Thread stack overrun) when I run this procedure, resolution of this error is not the objective of this question.

It would be nice to pass all parameters to stored procedure.

I'm trying to find a solution to execute all at once within a stored procedure, maybe it is simpler to make multiple INSERT queries, but probably there could be a better way

Comment: Do you need 15 tables?

Comment: No, I need to save Contract values in my database, which have 15 tables, and fields for all this values. My problem is I don't know how is better to save all this values, maybe using one query calling a stored procedure and passing all values as parameters than using procedure login to save all data, but I get an error #1436 - Thread stack overrun

Comment: @MarkBannister No it is not duplicate,  I'm trying to make a stored procedure and pass more than 60 parameters to it, and then I save values in my database tables, My question is how to do this correctly when I have so many values, it is fine using stored procedures or there is a better way

Comment: @MarkBannister I have edited my question a bit,  my question is to find the best way to save a contract with over 60 values

Comment: Edited question to emphasise that resolution of the error is not the main point.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. Are you asking if you should or should not use a stored procedure? You can do both. There are some cases you require a procedure (e.g. if your user should not have direct write access to your tables), and it might be favourable if you have several client apps (e.g php, c#, ...) to reuse code. Since you didn't mention anything like that, it's entirely opinion based and will depend on your coding style/your personal preferences/what you are most comfortable with. (Although a survey would propably, in my opinion, strongly trend to one direction).

Comment: We still haven't understood why you need 15 tables for this.

Comment: @Strawberry Because the contract paper has entities like consultant, contractor, beneficiary, etc.. and I have to populate all this tables with contract details, to save the contract, but also, there may be some cases like when consultant already exists..etc

Answer (score 2):

I hope I got your point, you can possibly do this two different ways -

One is to write a procedure with all 60 values as parameters and with insert queries inside the procedure you can insert data dynamically into all the 15 tables.

Otherwise, you can write a trigger with "after insert" on one main table and inside that trigger with input queries you can insert the data into multiple tables.

Comment: It is good idea using trigger for a table where all fields are keys. thanks

Comment: I guess it shouldn't be a problem, I had dealt with many large(schema) tables with lots of keys and dint had any issues.